# Modify xml using AJAX

Tags: ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have the following xml file:

```
<User>
    <Address>123</Address>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <SecondName>Smith</FirstName>
</User>
```

I am trying to get it changed with an AJAX call:

```
var addressid= = 123;
    $.ajax({
                                                    type: "GET",
                                                    url: url,
                                                    headers: {
                                                    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("username:password"),
                                                    },
                                                    contentType: "application/xml",
                                                    dataType: "xml",
                                                    async: true,
                                                    crossDomain: true,
                                                    success: function(xmlResponse) {
                                                    alert("Your user has been edited");
                                                    $(xmlResponse).find('User').each(function(){
                                                                                     if($(this).find('Address').text() == addressid) {
                                                                                     $(this).find('FirstName').text("Jenifer");
                                                                                     $(this).find('SecondName').text(secondName);
                                                                                     }
                                                                                     });
                                                    }
                                                    });
```

An alert comes, this does not display any errors, but it doesn't get passed on to the system. Which means, if I fetch the data from the server, the old name gets displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect you have to cast the type of your address to number before check for equality in the line if($(this).find('Address').text() == addressid)

Comment: If I understand it correctly this is what you mean: var currentAddress = $(this).find('Address').text() if( currentAddress == addressid) -> it's still not working..

Comment: If the ajax call is returning the correct XML and your data are not updated, then the problem should be with your checking on the address id try to make sure its passing the condition